# Whats the recommended way to cache 'expensive' queries in an MVC HTML Helper?

Tags: model-view-controller, html-helper, outputcache

I am trying to use output caching on an HTML Helper.  However, even with the attribute set, this code block is always entered when the Helper method is called.  Since the outputcache attribute won't work in this scenario, what would be the recommended way of caching "expensive" queries in Html Helpers?

```
     [OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
     public static MvcHtmlString CountryDropDownListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object selectedValue)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/countries.xml"));

        var items = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//country"))
        {
            items.Add(node.InnerText, node.InnerText);
        }

        return html.DropDownListFor(expression, new SelectList(items, "key", "value", selectedValue));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Output caching lets you store the output of an action method in memory on the Web server. For example, if the action method renders a view, the view page will be cached. This cached page is then available to the application for subsequent requests. Output caching saves your application the time and resources it would take to re-create the result of the action method.

In ASP.NET MVC, you can use the OutputCacheAttribute attribute to mark action methods whose output you want to cache. If you mark a controller with the OutputCacheAttribute attribute, the output of all action methods in the controller will be cached.

details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

***You use this attribure for not action method***

Correct Example

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 50000)]
public ActionResult CountryDropDownListFor()
{
   // Code 
}
```

And in your view you can use Html.PartialAction to render one